# Regex pattern "\{\{*Tag*\}\}" can't replace xml string

Tags: c#, regex

source xml string

```
                <w:tc>
                    <w:tcPr>
                        <w:tcW w:w="1870" w:type="dxa"/>
                    </w:tcPr>
                    <w:p w14:paraId="4A2404F3" w14:textId="6CC57F74" w:rsidR="00B721B4" w:rsidRDefault="00B721B4">
                        <w:r>
                            <w:t>{{</w:t>
                        </w:r>
                        <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
                        <w:r>
                            <w:t>CreateDate</w:t>
                        </w:r>
                        <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
                        <w:r>
                            <w:t>}}</w:t>
                        </w:r>
                    </w:p>
                </w:tc>
```

expect

```
<w:r>
    <w:t>2022-09-20</w:t>
</w:r>
```

I tried to use below regex and C# code to replace but it did not work.[online demo](https://regex101.com/r/ie8DSm/1)

```
void Main()
{
    var input = @"<w:r>
    <w:t>{{</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type=""spellStart""/>
<w:r>
    <w:t>CreateDate</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type=""spellEnd""/>
<w:r>
    <w:t>}}</w:t>
</w:r>";
    var pattern = @"\{\{*CreateDate*\}\}";
    var output = Regex.Replace(input,pattern,"2022-09-20");
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

[image]

I think `*` between `{}` can replace it, could friends give me idea about my mistakes, really appreciate!

### Update2:

I tried to use `\{\{.+Company_Name.+\}\}` but it get full string between first `{{` and last `}}`, [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/w9i31y/1)
[image]

Comment: Why are you using regex for this when XSLT and XPath are the more applicable solutions?

Comment: @TanveerBadar I'm trying create a xml template tool, it use string pattern like vue `{{tag}}`

Comment: Before writing it in C#, check it manually online on sites like https://regex101.com/

Comment: Required reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14868997. Do not use Regex for XML parsing, use a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is there are two issues.

1. You aren't matching "any character after {{". It should be `.*` instead of just `*`
2. I think you aren't matching multi-line. You'll need specify the match for `newline` as well: `(.|\n)*` instead of `.*`

Giving you the regex string:

```
\{\{(.|\n)*CreateDate(.|\n)*\}\}
```

You might be able to use a simpler regex `\{\{.*CreateDate.*\}\}` by setting `RegexOptions.Multline`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: `{{[^{}]*CreateDate[^{}]*}}`